# ggplot2: how to show full timestamp (with milliseconds) on x- axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

options(digits.secs=3)

dataframe <- data_frame(gmt_time = ymd_hms(c('2016-07-08 04:30:10.690',
                                     '2016-07-08 04:30:10.693',
                                     '2016-07-08 04:30:10.695',
                                     '2016-07-08 04:30:10.698',
                                     '2016-07-08 04:30:10.699')), 
                        value = c(1,2,3,4,5))
> dataframe
# A tibble: 5 × 2
                 gmt_time value
                   <dttm> <dbl>
1 2016-07-08 04:30:10.690     1
2 2016-07-08 04:30:10.693     2
3 2016-07-08 04:30:10.694     3
4 2016-07-08 04:30:10.697     4
5 2016-07-08 04:30:10.698     5
```

Now plotting this with vertical x-axis labels gives:

```
dataframe %>% ggplot(., aes(x = gmt_time, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I am unable to make my timestamp appear on the x-axis... What is wrong here? Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_1.1.0     tidyr_0.6.1     tibble_1.3.0    ggplot2_2.2.1  
[7] tidyverse_1.1.1 lubridate_1.6.0 hms_0.3
```

Comment: that is weird... what can I do?

Comment: And what about this ? `dataframe$gmt_time <- as.POSIXlt(dataframe$gmt_time)$sec`

Comment: yeah does not really work in more general cases I am afraid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I found the reason why this wasn't working - because your scale was too small for the default calculated breaks in `ggplot`. If you specify the breaks yourself it should work:

```
ggplot(dataframe) + geom_point(aes(x = gmt_time, y = value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq(from = min(dataframe$gmt_time), to = max(dataframe$gmt_time), by = 0.004))
```

[image]

Comment: nice one! but is it possible to have regularly spaced breaks then? say every 200 milliseconds

Comment: @Noobie see my edits. I use `seq` to go from the `min` of your time to the `max` of your time. The breaks are every 0.004 seconds (4 milliseconds). You can update the breaks by changing the `by`